# Formula issue in SQL when one result has 0 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a script that does some formulas in the select statement.

```
SUM(PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]/(PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY])) AS 'VAR Vs LY %'
```

When I run the script I am getting following error :

> Divide by zero error encountered.

How can I catch when there is a 0 value and just display 0 instead?

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: SQL Server?????

Comment: Running the outdated 2005

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the denumerator of the division is zero, and return `NULL` instead in this case. This will cause the division to return `NULL` as well, which is likely what you want.

Without knowing your RDBMS, here is an implementation that relies on a `CASE`statement, which is supported in most (if not all) SQL servers.

```
SUM(PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]/(
    CASE WHEN PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY] = 0 
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]
    END
)) AS 'VAR Vs LY %'
```

If your RDBMS supports `NULLIF`, then :

```
SUM(PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]/(
    NULLIF( PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY], 0)
)) AS 'VAR Vs LY %'
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT case when mod((5/(decode(0,0,5,1))),1) = 0 then 0 else (5/(decode(0,0,5,1))) end 
FROM dual;
0

SELECT case when mod((5/(decode(2,0,5,2))),1) = 0 then 0 else (5/(decode(2,0,5,2))) 
end 
FROM dual;
 2.5
```

for your case :

```
SELECT sum(case when mod((PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]/(decode((PMC.[Net Sales] - 
PMCLY.[Net Sale LY],0,5,(PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]))),1) = 0 
then 0 else (5/(decode((PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY],0,5,(PMC.[Net 
Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY])))) end 
FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

U can make use of a combination of the NULLIF and ISNULL functions. The NULLIF can be used to prevent the divide by zero errors. The ISNULL can be wrapped on the outside, to set a default value in such cases. In your case, that would be 0.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL (10 / NULLIF (0, 0) , 0)  -- result = 0
```

Your code example would look like this:

```
ISNULL (SUM (PMCLY.[Net Sale LY] / NULLIF ( (PMC.[Net Sales] - PMCLY.[Net Sale LY]), 0 ) ), 0) AS 'VAR Vs LY %'
```